# Variation of Integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, bounded-variation

Suppose $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$. Prove that

$$
V_{[a,b]}(F) = \int_a^b |f(t)|dt,
$$
where $V_{[a,b]}(F)$ denotes the variation of $F$ on $[a,b]$.

**Attempt**
Let $\mathcal{P}=\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_k\}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$. We have

\begin{align*}
V_{[a,b]}(F,\mathcal{P}) &= \sum_{i=1}^k \left| F(x_i) - F(x_{i-1}) \right|\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^k \left| \int_a^{x_i} f(t)dt - \int_a^{x_{i-1}} f(t)dt \right|
\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^k \left|\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} f(t)dt \right|\\
\end{align*}

Not sure how to get the absolute value inside the integral then the rest follows obviously.

Comment: What have you tried? Efforts...

Comment: Ok here what I have so far, sorry forgot to post it I'll update the main question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Total Variation and indefinite integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453694/total-variation-and-indefinite-integrals)